# python bdd framwork. how do we create same steps in multiple feature file

Tags: python-3.x, cucumber, python-behave, pytest-bdd

I would like to use steps from one feature file in another feature file with additional steps

```
feature file 1
secenario outline: sample test
  Given step 1 with id
  then step 2 with name 
  and step 3 with address
|id | name | address|
|1 | rahul | usa |


feature file 2
secenario outline: sample test
  Given step 1 with id
  then step 2 with name 
  when step 3 with id and name and location
  and step 3 with address
|id | name | address| location |
|1 | rahul | usa | hyd|
```

in practiacal i have more 23 steps to validate in my process. but when it comes to some other client i need to execute some additional steps to validate.

I am not able to skip the steps based on client. so i planned to create new feature file and copy the same steps again. but i have following issue

```
bheave.step_registry.Ambiguousstep
```

Please guide me how to resolve the issue

Comment: if you have multiple variables in the step, why not to use the setup table like you have in step 3 with values for id, name, address and location. Then you can fill in the data you need and reuse the same step for other clients

Comment: Clients that have similar conditions can be used via data table, But when it comes where i need to use some conditions that are not similar i need to use different strategy which i am not able to figure it out